# C basic programming concept

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am writing a program to do 3DES encryption.

But there are some fundamental mistakes in this code such as doing malloc within the function and not deallocating. Could someone help me in rewriting this by using a global variable and then deallocating? I want to optimize this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#define BUFSIZE 128 


char *
Encrypt( char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
{

        static char*    Res;
        unsigned char in[BUFSIZE], out[BUFSIZE], back[BUFSIZE];
        unsigned char *e = out;
        char buffer[21]="";
        char *pbuffer = buffer;
        int len;

        DES_cblock key1, key2, key3;
        DES_cblock seed = {0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10};
        DES_cblock ivsetup = {0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8};
        DES_cblock ivec;
        DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

        memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
        memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));
        memset(back, 0, sizeof(back));

        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key1);
        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key2);
        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key3);

        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key1, &ks1);
        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key2, &ks2);
        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key3, &ks3);

        strcpy(in, Msg);

        //printf("In Encrypt, Plaintext: [%s]\n", in);

        len = strlen(in);
        memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
        DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(in, out, len, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT);

        //printf("In Encrypt, Ciphertext:");
        while (*e) 
        {
            //printf("%02x", *e);
            sprintf(pbuffer, "%02x", *e);
            pbuffer +=2;
            *e++;
        }
        //printf("\n");
        //printf("In Encrypt, Returning Text: [%s]\n", buffer);

        Res = ( char * ) malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        memcpy(Res, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        return(( unsigned char * )Res);
}

char *
Decrypt( char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
{

        static char*    Res;

        unsigned char in[BUFSIZE], out[BUFSIZE], back[BUFSIZE];
        unsigned char *e = out;
        char buffer[21] = "";
        char *pbuffer = buffer;
        int len;

        DES_cblock key1, key2, key3;
        DES_cblock seed = {0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10};
        DES_cblock ivsetup = {0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8};
        DES_cblock ivec;
        DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

        memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
        memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));
        memset(back, 0, sizeof(back));

        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key1);
        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key2);
        DES_string_to_key (Key, &key3);

        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key1, &ks1);
        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key2, &ks2);
        DES_set_key((C_Block *)key3, &ks3);

        strcpy(in, Msg);

        //printf("In Decrypt, Plaintext: [%s]\n", in);

        len = strlen(in);
        memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
        DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(in, out, len, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivec, DES_DECRYPT);

        //printf("In Decrypt, Ciphertext:");
        while (*e) 
        {
            //printf("%02x", *e);
            sprintf(pbuffer, "%02x", *e);
            pbuffer +=2;
            *e++;
        }
        //printf("\n");
        //printf("In Decrypt, Returning Text: [%s]\n", buffer);

        Res = ( char * ) malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        memcpy(Res, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        return(( unsigned char * )Res);
}

int main(void)
{
    char key[]="1234567890123456"; // 16
    char clear[]="Arun Das";
    char *decrypted;
    char *encrypted;

    printf("In Main, Plain text\t : %s \n",clear);
    encrypted=Encrypt(key,clear,sizeof(clear));
    decrypted=Decrypt(key,encrypted,sizeof(encrypted)); 
    printf("In Main, Encrypted text\t : %s \n",encrypted);
    printf("In Main, Decrypted text\t : %s \n",decrypted);
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You seriously need to properly format your code...

Comment: Introducing a global variable to help managing memory is not a good idea.

Comment: @TToni: i was just doing this for someone else and i ve no clue of C...yea...i thght of that tested lib..but this seems to be the requirement... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a global variable - instead use `free()` on returned pointers once the calling code (`main()`) is done with the results.

Your implementation is quite good - both functions allocate memory and *pass ownership of it* to the calling code. The calling code becomes responsible for freeing that memory. This is concise and clear. Introducing a global variable will make it worse.

Think of it this way - `malloc()` does the same (except it allocates memory and doesn't fill it). How could `malloc()` be done clearer with a global variable accessible to the calling code?

Comment: so i ll have to do free(encrypted) and similarly for decrypted is it>?

Comment: @Arun Abraham : Yes, but only after you've done those `printf()` s.

Comment: it was just that i didnt know where i could do the dealloc...thats why...doing the free(encrypted) is enough is it???

Comment: @Arun Abraham: You have to deallocate all the memory you've allocated. Since both `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` return pointers to allocated memory you have to `free()` both `encrypted` and `decrypted`.

Comment: free(encrypted);
    free(decrypted);   have added these two lines after printf.. this should take care of the mem alloc right...

Comment: @Arun Abraham: Yeap, that will mark that memory as unallocated, so that subsequent `malloc()` calls can again return it.